In django DRF using JWT, why does postman properly block access to some views but they are available from my Angular front-end without authentication?
I’m trying to restrict access to some views of my API using Django Rest Framework and simpleJWT https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/
The issue I’m facing is that postman correctly blocks access to my views when I do not provide a valid JWT to my API but my Angular front-end does not and gives access to all the views of my DRF API.
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}

Here is a beginning of a view with
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from ..serializer import General_emission_group_serializer_years
from django.db import connection

class EmmissionGroup(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self, request):

Here is my settings.py
from pathlib import Path
import os
import environ
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.staticfiles import handlers

class CORSStaticFilesHandler(handlers.StaticFilesHandler):
    def serve(self, request):
        response = super().serve(request)
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        return response

handlers.StaticFilesHandler = CORSStaticFilesHandler

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
 
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env"))
 
SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")

DEBUG = True
 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1"]
 
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "corsheaders",
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    #"rest_framework.authtoken",
    "django_filters",
    "camping",
    "admin_honeypot",
    "axes",   
]
 
 
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', # Token-based authentication for API
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', # Default Django authentication backend 
    'axes.backends.AxesStandaloneBackend',
]
 
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'axes.middleware.AxesMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    

]

AXES_ENABLED = True
AXES_COOLOE_NAME = 'axes'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'WebCamping.urls'
 
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
 
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'WebCamping.wsgi.application'
 
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

#CORS
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:4200",
]
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'DELETE',
]
 
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
 
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
 
USE_I18N = True
 
USE_TZ = True
 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
         "C:/Projets/Stage/Camping/WebCamping/camping/static",
         ]
 
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

And my urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)
from camping.views.camping_view import CampingViewSet
from camping.views.client_view import ClientViewSet
from camping.views.adresse_view import AdresseViewSet

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

[importing views]

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'client', ClientViewSet)
router.register(r'camping', CampingViewSet)
router.register(r'adresse', AdresseViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    [some path]
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('', include(router.urls))

What do you recommend to treat this kind of problem? I tried postman and the job of blocking restricted wiews seems to be done with that tool. I suspect a CORS problem but not sure about that.

I can see that your view actually require JWT Token to be presented in headers
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

If you intended to allow users to access this endpoint without authentication you can change it to
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

AllowAny gives access to all methods (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, HEAD and DELETE if they're implemented) without any authentication
Also, you can use ReadOnly for safe_methods (GET and HEAD)
    permission_classes = [ReadOnly || IsAuthenticated]

Note:  || IsAuthenticated is used to give your authenticated users access to all method, while ReadOnly prohibits it. If you have only a get method you can stick with:
    permission_classes = [ReadOnly]

